# Opening new window with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to open a new window from an action on my main window.

I have a main window layout `MainWindow.axml`:

```
<Window x:Name="Capacity_Restrictions" x:Class="PayloadRestrictions.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PayloadRestrictions"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Capacity Restrictions" Height="551.677" Width="879.614">
        ...

</Window>
```

And then the window I want to open `EditTextWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Name="Capacity_Restrictions" x:Class="PayloadRestrictions.EditTextWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PayloadRestrictions"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Editing" Height="100" Width="100">
        ...   
</Window>
```

And then inside my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I have:

```
namespace PayloadRestrictions
{
    public partial class EditTextWindow : Window
    {
        public EditTextWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window

    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
                // Some operations with this row
                var window = new EditTextWindow();
                window.Show();
            }
            ...
        }
     }
```

And every time I try to build the project I am getting an error on the `InitializeComponent();` line within the `EditTextWindow` partial class:

`The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context   PayloadRestrictions`

Any suggestions for what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you add the file for the second window? If you're using Visual Studio, you can add a new WPF Window directly via the UI, and it should set up everything correctly (including a new code behind file).

Comment: If that's actually your code you've nested an event handler inside a constructor. There should be a closing curly brace after `InitializeComponent`

Comment: I went to the folder where the `MainWindow.axml` file was and made a copy of it and modified it

Comment: If you copied the file you've also copied the xaml and if you've not updated the class name in the xaml and there's no auto generated designer file then you won't have an InitializeComponent method in the first place. Creating a window using the IDE does a bit of setup for you. Creating a window class manually is going to result in missing bits.

Comment: Using the IDE did it for me, I've solved the issue now. Move the comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

One problem, at least, is that both windows have the same name in your xaml files.

The solution is to break them out as separate files, as Andy was indicating. Then you can just launch the child window, like:

```
EditTextWindow window = new EditTextWindow();
window.Show();
```